# string = string.trim(); bad practice?

Tags: java

Ok I am using Sonar to check code quality. It's telling me this simple method is causing two Major warnings.

```
public static String formatString(String string) {
    if(string==null) {
        return null;
    }
    string = string.trim();
    string = string.toUpperCase();
    return string;
}
```

Where I can understand the warning due to direct access to the parameter. As you can see this method pretty much does very little. Removes whitespace and puts it in caps. However what is the problem since it in the end returns a string. The creation of a value holder string seems excess to requirements given the overhead in creating a string.

So my question is what I'm doing bad coding and if so why?

Comment: What are the warnings you get?

Comment: Your code haven't any problem and execute correctly but you have to observe these notes: 1. parameter name isn't good, select a better name such as `input_str` or `raw_str`. 2.Programming best practies saye: a method or function have a input point and a output point,it is better you have a `return` statement.

Comment: @MJM: You are right about the parameter, but I also have read that using "guarding conditionals" is also a best practice. In this case having more than one return-statement is ok. Just my 0.02 ;)

Comment: @MJM How is `input_str` more descriptive. Aren't all parameters inputs? And what does 'raw' mean? Sometimes inputs are just arbitrary strings without further meaning. See the StringBuilder parameter names for example.

Comment: @fgb: At least it's not a good practice to use class-/type-names as variable-names. Call it "inputString", "stringToWorkWith" or whatever and everyone knows what this piece of code does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think that you are doing anything wrong: although the whole code can be folded to a single line like this

```
return string == null ? null : string.trim().toUpperCase();
```

I know people who prefer to see it on multiple lines. The compiler should figure out all necessary optimizations related two writing back to `string` "unnecessarily", so I think you're good.

Comment: you've moved my code into one line. This is the first time I have ever seen a ? if statement. I'm guessing the : is the else. Have you a reference for these?

Comment: @Will [absolutely!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) It is called "ternary operation", because it consists of three parts - the condition, the "when true" result, and the "when false" result. Unlike `if` which is a *statement*, ternary operation is an *expression*.

Comment: Ternary statements like this work awesomely but I usually avoid if there are new juniors around as it is much less readable, this does not take away from the correctness of this answer (see my answer below) +1

Comment: @Will: Take note of the link to ?: at the top of the page dasblinkenlight links to.

Comment: The name of that particular ternary operator is the conditional operator.

Answer (score 4):

Well, *some* coders might assume that the parameter value won't be changed. I *usually* wouldn't change the parameter, but in a method this short I'd be content to do so. On the other hand, I'd probably write it as:

```
public static String formatString(String text) {
    return text == null ? null : text.trim().toUpperCase();
}
```

I'd also probably change the name of the method, and give a locale to `toUpperCase`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I see nothing really wrong with your code. I'd write it like this (after the null check):

```
return string.trim().toUpperCase();
```

This avoids modifying a parameter which often makes code easier to analyse. However, in a routine as trivial as this I don't see that as a valid concern.

Answer (score 2):

Given that your example works if coded like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String greeting = "Hello greetings ";
    String greeting2 = formatString(greeting);

    System.out.println("Hi ["+greeting +"]");
    System.out.println("Hi ["+greeting2 +"]");
}

private static String formatString(String string) {
    if(string==null) {
        return null;
    }
    string = string.trim();
    string = string.toUpperCase();
    return string;
}
```

It will be complaining that you are modifying the argument directly, in java this isn't really an issue seeing as the resulting code ends up with the output

```
Hi [Hello greetings ]
Hi [HELLO GREETINGS]
```

however its a bad habit to get into given other languages do not behave this way and you could have modified the original variable so that the output would be

```
Hi [HELLO GREETINGS]
Hi [HELLO GREETINGS]
```

It is also less readable, most coding standards I've seen say do not directly modify incomming arguments unless you are changing the underlying reference entirely AND it is obvious from the signature that this will happen.

I tend to avoid like the plague this type of code (out of habit) so I would say yes its bad practise but its not technically incorrect.

for completeness I would have written **formatString** like this

```
private static String formatString(String string) {
    String output = null;

    if (string != null) {
        output = string.trim().toUpperCase();
    }

    return output;
}
```

I accept I could use a ternary test here (the `?` operator) and do it all on one line but I tend to think thats less readable for more junior guys so again I avoid that and I think this is more readable, but that is of course.... my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is because you change the input variable. In some conventions [such as spartan programming] it is considered a bad practice to change the value of the input.

Some conventions like using the variable `$`, if it also contains the return value:

just put `String $ = string;` at the first line of your code - and use `$` instead of `string` on the rest of the method.

The real "spartan way" will be to use the trinary  operator `(cond ? val1 : val2)` to check for null, and return `string.trim().toUpperCase()` alltogether.

---

**EDIT:**

Though stated some conventions supports using the variable `$` when it comes to return value, as @StephenC stated, it is a bad practice, since it [the `$`] is reserved for generated source code,

Comment: *"Some conventions like using the variable `$` ..."* - BAD, EVIL ... The JLS states categorically that `$` is reserved for use by compilers, code generators and so on.  If you use it in regular Java code you might find that nasty things happen, either now or in some other context where your code is reused.

Comment: @StephenC: thanks for the tip. do you have a reference for that?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8 - It says *"[t]he $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems."*.  In fact the Java compiler uses `$` in inner class names and synthetic variable names.

Comment: @StephenC: I added indication for that in the answer. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

The style checker is really complaining that you are modifying the value of a method argument.  A lot of people would stay that this is bad style.  It makes it harder to read the code because people don't expect argument values to be changed.  (That's kind of a circular argument, but it does reflect the way that many people *actually do* read/misread code.)

A more stylish solution is this:

```
public static String formatString(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String tmp = string.trim();
    tmp = tmp.toUpperCase();
    return tmp;
}
```

or ....

```
public static String formatString(String string) {
    return (string == null) ? null :
           string.trim().toUpperCase();
}
```